# How to get access to admin privileges on standard-user OS X?

Tags: mac, administrator, macos-highsierra, standard-user

After reinstalling the OS X I only have access to standard user.

Is there a way to create/change an admin account when I don´t have admin privileges?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can cause the first-boot Setup Assistant to run again, and use it to create a local admin account.

1. Boot into single-user mode by holding down Cmd-S at boot time. Follow the on-screen instructions to remount the boot volume read/write.
2. `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`
   `reboot`
3. When your Mac reboots, the Setup Assistant will run. Follow the normal Setup Assistant flow to create a new local admin account.
4. If you wanted your old account to be an administrator, use your new local admin account to grant admin privs to your old account. You can then log out of the new account, log back into the old account, and then delete the new account if you want.

Answer (score -2):

Whoever performed the reinstall should have had to set up an administrative account for the machine. There should be no way for an unprivileged user to create an admin account or promote a standard account to an admin account.